# Compiling java program from command line passing args

Tags: java

I wrote a simple java program

```
package abc.def.ghi 
public class Foobar{


   public String printS(String s){
     System.Out.println(s);

 public static void main(String [] args){
   String s = args[0];
   Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
    foobar.printS(s);
}
```

Now I did javac Foobar.java

It created a class file

and then I did

```
java Foobar
```

Didnt worked

```
 java Foobar hi //args
```

Didnt worked

java -cp . abc.def.ghi.Main

DIdnt worked.

Error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: abc/def/ghi/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.conf.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.intel.hadoop.graphbuilder.conf.Main.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: java -cp . abc.def.ghi.Foobar hi

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with passing command line parameters. You have a classpath / package name issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put your `.class` files in the path `(path to project)/abc/def/ghi/Foobar.class`?

```
NoClassDefFoundError: abc/def/ghi/Foobar
```

Looks like you didn't.

Comment: @Fraz Move `Main.class` files to `(path to project)/abc/def/ghi/Main.class` perhaps?

Comment: It would be Foobar.class, not Main.class.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Oh, right. (*reminds self to read question better*)

Answer (score 1):

If you compile using

```
javac -d . Foobar.java
```

then the compiler will put the `.class` file in the right directory to match its package name, then

```
java abc.def.ghi.Foobar
```

should run it successfully.